# Custom navigation with Swiper 9 and SvelteKit

Tags: swiper.js, sveltekit

I managed to put the default navigation buttons of swiper.js, but I would like to be able to set up custom buttons and use the `slideNext()` and `slidePrev()` methods when clicking on them.

Unfortunately, I tried several methods, but nothing worked, and I have no idea how to do this with SvelteKit.

My code :

```html
<script>
    import SwiperSlide from './SwiperSlide.svelte';

    import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
    register();
</script>

<swiper-container
    navigation={true}
    slides-per-view={1}
    direction="horizontal"
    space-between={30}
    centered-slides={true}
    keyboard={true}
    pagination={{
        hideOnClick: false,
        clickable: true
    }}
>
    <SwiperSlide id={1} />
    <SwiperSlide id={0} />
    <SwiperSlide id={2} />
</swiper-container>

<style>
    swiper-container {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100vh;
        max-height: 1000px;
        padding: 50px 0;
    }
</style>
```

`<SwiperSlide>` is a component with a `<swiper-slide></swiper-slide>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by initializing `Swiper` from the constructor. I made [an example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-swiper-v9?file=src%2Froutes%2FSwiper.svelte).

```js
<script>
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
import Swiper from 'swiper';

register();

let swiperEl, swiperObj = null;

function goPrev() {
  console.log("clicked: prev")
  swiperObj.slidePrev();
}

function goNext() {
  console.log("clicked: next")
  swiperObj.slideNext();
}

onMount(() => {
  // swiper element
  swiperObj = new Swiper(swiperEl, {
    navigation: false,
    pagination: false,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 2500,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    loop: true,
  });
  // console.log(swiperObj)
});
</script>
```

```html
<swiper-container bind:this={swiperEl}>
  <swiper-slide>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>

<div class="custom-navigation">
  <button on:click={goPrev}>Previous</button>
  <button on:click={goNext}>Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

hope it can help you

```
<script lang="ts">
    import SliderGrid from '$components/Slider/SliderGrid.svelte';
    import type { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper';
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/svelte';
    const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let touchMove = true;

    let swiper: Swiper;
    $: activeSnapIndex = 0;
    $: snapGridTotal = 1;
    const breakpoints = {
        320: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerGroup: 2,

            grid: {
                rows: 2
            }
        },
        // when window width is >= 480px
        480: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerGroup: 3,
            grid: {
                rows: 2
            }
        },
        // when window width is >= 640px
        640: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerGroup: 4,
            grid: {
                rows: 2
            }
        },
        // when window width is >= 640px
        1024: {
            slidesPerView: 5,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerGroup: 5,

            grid: {
                rows: 2
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<div>
    {touchMove}
    <button
        type="button"
        on:click={() => {
            touchMove = !touchMove;
            swiper.allowTouchMove = touchMove;
            console.log(swiper?.allowTouchMove);
        }}>toggle</button
    >
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
        <button
            type="button"
            class="i-carbon-chevron-left"
            on:click={() => {
                swiper?.slidePrev();
            }}>prev</button
        >
        <span>{activeSnapIndex + 1} / {snapGridTotal}</span>
        <button
            type="button"
            class="i-carbon-chevron-right"
            on:click={() => {
                swiper?.slideNext();
                console.log(swiper.snapIndex);
            }}>next</button
        >
    </div>
    <Swiper
        spaceBetween={10}
        slidesPerView="auto"
        {breakpoints}
        on:slideChange={() => {
            activeSnapIndex = swiper.snapIndex;
        }}
        on:resize={() => {
            snapGridTotal = swiper?.snapGrid.length;
        }}
        on:swiper={(e) => {
            swiper = e.detail[0];
            activeSnapIndex = swiper.snapIndex;
            snapGridTotal = swiper?.snapGrid.length;
            console.log(swiper);
        }}
    >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is unrelated to version 9 of Swiper